# Issues Running and Debugging Spring Boot Gradle application in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, gradle, spring-data-jpa

I have imported a gradle spring boot project in Eclipse (latest version). When I go to Gradle Tasks -> bootRun. I am able to run the gradle tasks. The application is working fine and am able to call controller classes using Postman.

[image]

But, I need to debug the code. So, I right click on project and Debug As -> Java Application. But application fails to run with following error

```
    ERROR o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
    IO Error: IO Error PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: IO Error PKIX path building failed:..
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed:
```

Why I can bootRun the application but not Debug As -> Java Application

Comment: What happens when you *Run As* -> Java Application? What does the *bootRun* task do differently?

Comment: @nitind It is the same error message as shown above for Debug As.